# AccountContactRelation Variable In Apex Controller

Tags: apex, controller, custom-controller

I'm not receving any errors in the following, however the table in the VF page is not rendering. Would appreciate any advice on what is incorrect here, or if I'm completely going about this wrong.

```
public class ContactReports 
{
    public List<Project__c> rprt {get; set;}
    public list<AccountContactRelation> acr {get; set;}
    public ContactReports() {
        
        AccountContactRelation acr = [
        SELECT AccountId, ContactId 
        FROM AccountContactRelation 
        WHERE ContactId = :UserInfo.getUserId()              
        ];
        
        this.rprt = [
            
            Select Id,
            Name,
            AccountName__c,
            Account__c,
            ProductName__c
            
            FROM Project__c WHERE Status__c IN ('Active', 'Completed') AND Account__r.Id = :acr.AccountId ];
    }
}
```

For reference, I was successful with the following, but I'd like it to be based on AccountContactRelation object instead:

```
public class ContactReports 
{
    public List<Project__c> rprt {get; private set; }
    public ContactReports() {
        User u = [Select ContactId From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
        this.rprt = [
            
            Select Id,
            Name,
            AccountName__c,
            Account__c,
            ProductName__c
            
            FROM Project__c WHERE Status__c IN ('Active', 'Completed') AND Customer_Point_of_Contact__c = :u.ContactId ORDER BY AccountName__c ASC NULLS FIRST];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering `ContactId = :UserInfo.getUserId()`, which can never match. The left side looks for Id of `Contact` type, and the right side provides Id of `User` type. Even if you resolve this problem, the code is highly likely to fail, as one `Contact` can have many `AccountContactRelation` records looking up to it. So your first query should instead look like:

```
List<AccountContactRelation> relations = [
    SELECT AccountId FROM AccountContactRelation
    WHERE ContactId IN (
        SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
    )
];
```

Comment: Adjusting the first query as described worked. Thank you so much, Adrian.